# BeautifulSoup : Insert a line break with soup.get_text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all text under a specific class and a specific name from a site, so I can put it in an excel file after. However, when I'm using

```
soup.get_text("strong", {"class": "literal"})
```

on https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/ (this is just an example), I get all the text without a single line break. Is it possible to get the text just like on the site, with the corrects line breaks, paragraphs after paragraphs? Thanks!

Comment: How about using `.find_all('strong', attrs={"class": "literal"})` first, and then apply `.get_text`?

Comment: I tried `soup.get_text(soup.findAll("code", {"class" : "literal2"}))`, but I get AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'join'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: @Anthony soup.findall returns a list. get_text should be applied to each element of the list, not the list itself. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.join()` to print text with linebreaks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

print('\n'.join(strong.text for strong in soup.select('strong.literal')))
```

Prints:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://inventwithpython.com/')
pyperclip
else:
# Get address from clipboard.
address = pyperclip.paste()
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
import requests
import requests

...and so on.
```

Comment: Your code works very well, but obviously, one problem brings another ... I want to extract a text which is under <tr class="rowclick">, but because I dont have anymore a "strong" text before class, I dont really see how to adapt it ..

Comment: I see no `<tr class="rowclick">` on that page. What URL are your parsing now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy one-liner which you can use to replace your code-snippet:

```
results = list(map(lambda x: x.get_text(), soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "literal"})))
# or even better:
results = [el.get_text() for el in soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "literal"})]
```

This will result in a list getting the text of each element found that matches your search criteria. You can then use string-method (`str.join`) for this list as already [showed in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764647/2648551) or use a regular for-iteration:

```
for result in soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "literal"}):
    result = result.get_text()
    # proceed here, e. g.
    print(result)  # This will print out the site as wanted
```